# Hash function for sorting words from file

Tags: java, function, hash, colors, hashtable

I'm programing in Java that needs to read words from a file. The hash table needs to do the following:

1. Use JCF hashmap.
2. Count how many times it sees the word in the file.
3. Record the lines that the word has been seen.
4. My functions should not have more than 20 lines of code.

I am not sure how to do this efficiently as we are never told the final test problem.

My best guess was using alphabet and buckets (arrays, since binary search can be done easily) to hold the data and create string fields that will record the line, and int for number size it saw it.

thanks.

Comment: Write it then remove all the new line characters. Your guaranteed to only have one line ;).

Comment: Do you know what a JCF hashmap is? What will be your key, and what will be your value? Try starting from just counting the words, and then extend to recording all the lines.

Comment: It sounds like you have an approach. Try it and see how it goes. For recording just word counts, you can use a `Map<String, Integer>`, but for recording more information, you'll need a object (custom class) or tuple type for the values. Nevertheless, there's really nothing for an answerer to address in your question short of just writing the code for you. So try and see how it goes.

Comment: Real Skeptic, I have to do use the HashMap API. I am not sure what will be the test case... Using each color as hash location would be ideal, not sure how its done however.